# Create dynamic cities of perspective angle x

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm creating a tilemap... I found you can create unique building sizes with perspective with six tiles using [parallel projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection), whose angles are always $45^\circ$ .... this allows you to connect to the next tile without issue:

[image]

[image]

The issue with that is you're stuck to a $45^\circ$ angle... I feel like a 75 degree angle better matches my game's overall perspective...

[image]

But doing anything other than $45^\circ$ limits how deep my building is (how far back the building top goes)... so this seems to force me to create additional buildings if I want to make the top reach back further... Which adds complexity

[image]

[image]

**Question**:

Is there a way to achieve what I'm doing for any angle I choose such that I can create one building tile set (of 6 tiles) and create dynamic cities?

Or, do I have to sacrifice the angle of my choosing and go with the simple $45^\circ$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you limited to an integer grid?

Comment: Why does a 75° angle limit how deep your buildings can be?

Comment: $\tan75°$ can be approximated with increasing precision using $\frac31,\frac41,\frac{11}3,\frac{15}4,\frac{41}{11}$ so these might be slopes to aim for if you are limited to an integer grid. Continued fractions can give you estimates like these. The large numbers involved there indicate that you'll either need more tiles or larger tiles (w.r.t. the integer grid), but I don't understand your constraints well enough to judge which will be the case.